# How to order a elements of Jframe, specificly

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

I have a problem. I made a frame with a toolbar, 2 buttons below the toolbar, and finally down to a textPane.

This I did with the help of java frame.
But I want to order, with pure code.

What layouts I need, to do it this, like in the image?
Or how dot it...

**Image JFrame.**

[image]

Comment: did you do it?? show the code then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I would do as following;

Firstly, I would use `BorderLayout` in my JFrame. In `BorderLayout`, I would put the newly create JPanel on the top (`PAGE_START`) in the border layout.

Now, the `JPanel` is on the top of the GUI as your example. In this `JPanel`, I would use `FlowLayout` and add my components (buttons in your example) to the `JPanel`.

For more detail on BorderLayout and FlowLayout, you can find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html).

Comment: Thank you, this works fine with the buttons down of the toolbar. But how can I put the text area down of the buttons? I want to put text area down of the buttons, as the image example. I try to put a Panel as flow layout, but dont works, my buttons disapear. Thank you a so much for your time and help.